# As an Indian citizen residing in UK, do I require a Schengen Visa for travel to Switzerland via Paris?

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, uk-residents

I am an Indian residing in UK with a BRP. I am planning to travel to Switzerland by train (As a tourist for a week). The Eurostar takes me to Paris and then a connecting train to Zurich. As Paris is the transit station and Switzerland my final destination, do I need a Switzerland tourist visa or Schengen Tourist Visa ?

Comment: Both France and Switzerland are in the Schengen Area, so you will need a Schengen Visa (that is good for both).

Comment: "do I need a Switzerland tourist visa or Schengen Tourist Visa?": A Swiss tourist visa _is_ a Schengen visa.

Answer (score 6):

Switzerland and France are both in the Schengen area and as such you need a Schengen visa.
As an Indian citizen you need such a visa, your residency in the UK does not make a difference there.

Your stay in Switzerland is longer than the time you spend in France, there is no reason for France to be the more important visit (as far as I can see) so you need to apply from Switzerland.

Even when you travel by train you can use the airline sites for general visa information, but in this case I have searched for visa information from Switzerland.

[This page explains you need a Schengen visa.](https://www.ch.ch/en/foreign-nationals-in-switzerland/entry-and-stay-in-switzerland/visas-for-foreign-nationals#who-needs-a-visa) And this [page (from Switzerland) shows you need a visa as Indian citizen.](https://www.sem.admin.ch/sem/en/home/publiservice/weisungen-kreisschreiben/visa/liste1_staatsangehoerigkeit/i.html)

Comment: While the residency in the UK does no change the need for a visa it probably does have an impact on the likelyhood of being granted a visa. Residence and a job in the UK provide an easy proof that OP has the means to visit Switzerland as a tourist and make them look much less likely to attempt illegal immigration.